# sencha touch: 5 simple questions

Tags: javascript, html, touch, extjs

I am new to sencha touch and I have some simple questions. I don't need 100% working code as answers, but if someone could point me in the correct direction, this would be great. But keep in mind, sencha touch is new to me. I use sensha touch 1.x.

Let me first explain what my app does. It shows a list with items (fetched from a db via json proxy). You can tap on a item, which shows a form. You can then update or delete the item. On the list screen you can also add a new item. Quite simple :-)

**Here are my questions:**

**1/ Datepickerfield:**

In the form there is a `datepickerfield`. The default format is `month/day/year`. I live in Europe so the formate should be `day/month/year`. With `slotorder`, I can change this. But the field itself still has the wrong format. I tried to fix this with a listener:

```
change: function() {
this.fieldEl.dom.value = this.getValue().format('d/m/Y'); 
}
```

This works when selecting a date. But when tapping an item from the list, the `datepickerfield` remains the wrong format. I tried using other listeners like `afterrender`, `scope`, etc. But nothing works.

**2/ Numberfields:**

In the model I have a field `duration`. It is of the type `time` in the sql-table. So the format is `hh:mm:ss`. In the form I have 3 `numberfields`. One for the hour, one for the minutes and one for the seconds.

How can I make the field `duration` split up into 3 parts and filled in the 3 `numberfields` when tapping an items from the list?

**3/ Contextual selectfield**

In the form there is a `selectfield` with values that depend on the user that is logged in. If user 1 is logged in, the values should be `x`, `y`, `z`. If user 2 is logged in, the values should be `x`, `a`, `b`, etc.

So, when opening the form the `selectfield` should be pre-filled with data. It should call a function from the server to fetch the correct data. How can this be achieved?

**4/ Refresh list like twitter**

I want the list to fetch additional items when reaching the end (like twitter). I found something on the Internet: `PullRefresh` plugin. But I can't make it work.

Any ideas?

**5/ Style the list**

Is it possible to style each item of a list separately? You can use `styleHtmlCls`, etc but that styles the whole list.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1 - This is easy set:

```
picker: {
slotOrder: ["day","month","year"]
}
```

2 - I dont understand 2 give more clarity

3 - You need to use local storage for this

4 - For paging try this link [sencha list paging plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7321446/sencha-list-paging-plugin)

5 - You cant directly style each item differently but you can define a style for each item in the list by setting its style config

Comment: 1/ I used the slotorder and it works. But when i select an item from the list to view the details, the datepickerfield shows the date in the format "month/day/year"

Comment: 2/ In the sql database i have a field "duration" of the type "time". It is "hh:mm:ss". In my form i have 3 numberfields to modify the hours, minutes and seconds. My question is how i can get the value of the duration, split it and set the values of the numberfields.

Comment: 3/ Can you give more details? How do i call the function to fetch the data and how do i store is locally?

Comment: modify the dateFormat config to 'm/d/Y'

Answer (score 0):

For those who are interested, my solutions.

1/ This `code Ext.apply(Ext.util.Format, {defaultDateFormat: 'd/m/Y'});` which sets the format for all the dates in the application.

2/ I created in my model 3 extra fields. It are 3 "convert" fields for the field "duration" which is in format "hh:mm:ss". This is the code (the same for the fields duration_m and duration_s):

```
name: 'duration_h', 
            convert: function(value, record) 
{
           var duration= record.get('duration'), 
                 splits    = duration.split(":"), 
                 duration_h = splits[0];
           return duration_h;             
}
```

In my form I use now 3 numberfields linked to those 3 extra fields. When saving you data you must not forget to do
PHP Code:
model.set('duration_h', ''); 
Otherwise those fields are not set in the model and keep being empty.

3/ and 4/ I did not yet solved.