# Sencha list paging plugin doesn´t work properly

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am trying to implement a feature with the "ListPaging" Sencha plugin, and its working correctly but with the next case I am having an exception. Server sents the total count of rows, for example 10, but if I have the pagesize property configurated with 11 rows, plugin doesn´t work. Here a little piece of code with the store implementation:

```
store = Ext.create('Cicero.store.activity.Activities', {
            storeId: storeId,
            pageSize: 10,
            autoLoad: false,
            clearOnPageLoad: false
        });
```

This is the plugin implementation in the view:

```
            //LISTPAGING
        {
            xclass: 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
            autoPaging: true,
            loadMoreText : 'Loading more activities',
            noMoreRecordsText : 'All Activities loaded'
        }
    ],
    scrollable: true,
    onItemDisclosure: true,
    emptyText: 'No activities found',
```

Mainly the problem is: All is working correct but when the number of records returned is less than the page size, the plugin doesn´t work..

Any clue?

Comment: Can you share some more code, like how are you configuring the ListPaging plugin. Also, what does the server response look like when it fails for you?

Comment: Hi @mindparse I have added the code implemented in the view.